# Can you define the step order in the spring-batch dynamically?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I don't speak English that well. Please understand.

I use the Spring-boot and Spring-batch. It continues a project.

I know that beans related to a batch while all beans go up to the server early days same time go up together.

it was defined as A->B->C. If it is the case.

Is there the way in which I change into B->A->C this type and I can put into practice?

By using JobExecutionDecider, I was going to look for the way but as a step increases, the problem that the coding range is expanded is predicted.

When there are the StepA, StepB, and StepC for example.
A->B->C, A->C->B, B->A->C, B->C->A, C->A->B, C->B->A The number of 3!(=6) If I happen and get to do this for hanger.

```
.start(decider).on("A").to(StepA())
.next(decider).on("B").to(StepB()).next(StepC()).end()
.from(decider).on("C").to(StepC()).next(StepB()).end()
.from(decider).on("B").to(StepB())
.....
.....
```

Should you describe all case of 3!(=6) in this way?
The more if that happens, the number of Step increases, I increase by an exponential...

Doesn't something have the better way?

Comment: Why? If your batch jobs are that dynamic is it a batch job and/or is Spring Batch the right tool for the job.

Comment: Dynamically when?  As a job executes (changing from step to step) or is the order determined at startup?

Comment: As a job executes. (the order determined at startup already